# Why is $r \log\left(\frac{n+k}{k}\right)-\log\left(\frac{rn+k}{k}\right)$ equivalent to $r\log(n) - \log (rn)$ as $k\to 0$?

Tags: limits, logarithms

I read the following and I am not sure I understand it.

I have the equation:

$$r \log\left(\frac{n+k}{k}\right)-\log\left(\frac{rn+k}{k}\right)$$

All the variables are real numbers. It is said that the equation above, when $k=0$ or $k \to 0$, is equivalent to the expression:

$$r\log(n) - \log (rn)$$

I do not understand what the above is true. Is this so, and can anybody give me some insight into why this is the case?

Edit: Okay I got an idea, maybe using the fact that $\log(a/b)=log(a)-log(b)$ I can rewrite my expression as

$$   r \log(n+k)+r\log(k)-\log(rn+k)-\log(k)$$

and then with $k=0$

$$   r \log(n)-\log(rn)+(r-1)\log(k)$$

but then I guess the last term is going to $-\infty$ if $r>1$?

Comment: In the terms you are mentioning, I find that assertion unwarranted if not false. See for instance the case where all the variables are $>0$ and $r\ne1$. Then that quantity is $$r\log(n+k)-\log(rn+k)+(1-r)\log k$$ which diverges to $\operatorname{sgn}(r-1)\cdot\infty$ as $k\to 0^+$ with $n,r$ constant.

Comment: Well, when $k = 0$ those are simply undefined.  So only consider $k \to 0$ and take limits.

Comment: The 1st line may be called a formula or an expression, bur  not an equation, An equation is a sentence that says something is equal to something.

Comment: Yeah.... It's not true

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is a problem with the domain, If they are all real numbers that allows for negative logs which is undefined. It appears that there was either a mistake or the resource in which you found this is incorrect. As far as I can tell, as $k \to 0$ the equation goes to $+/-\infty$ (depending on the value of r), the only time I can see this hold true is when $r=1$ and thus the log(k) terms will cancel.